# FirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived override error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-cloud-messaging

Class:

```
class SubscriptionMessageService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

companion object {
    private val TAG = SubscriptionMessageService::class.java.simpleName
    private const val REMOTE_MESSAGE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY = "currentStatus"
}

override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    remoteMessage?.data?.let {
        val data = it
        if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
            var result: List<SubscriptionStatus>? = null
            if (REMOTE_MESSAGE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY in data) {
                result = data[REMOTE_MESSAGE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY]?.let {
                    SubscriptionStatus.listFromJsonString(it)
                }
            }
            if (result == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid subscription data")
            } else {
                val app = application as SubApp
                app.repository.updateSubscriptionsFromNetwork(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Error: 'onMessageReceived' overrides nothing

Github Link: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/ClassyTaxi/android/ClassyTaxi/app/src/main/java/com/example/subscriptions/data/network/firebase/SubscriptionMessageService.kt

Answer (score 5):

RemoteMessage is not nullable
you should change like that

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    val data = remoteMessage.data
    if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
        var result: List<SubscriptionStatus>? = null
        if (REMOTE_MESSAGE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY in data) {
            result = data[REMOTE_MESSAGE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY]?.let {
                SubscriptionStatus.listFromJsonString(it)
            }
        }
        if (result == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid subscription data")
        } else {
            val app = application as SubApp
            app.repository.updateSubscriptionsFromNetwork(result)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working this way:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    remoteMessage?.data?.let {
        val data = it
        if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
            var result: List<SubscriptionStatus>? = null
            if (REMOTE_MESSAGE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY in data) {
                result = data[REMOTE_MESSAGE_SUBSCRIPTIONS_KEY]?.let {
                    SubscriptionStatus.listFromJsonString(it)
                }
            }
            if (result == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid subscription data")
            } else {
                val app = application as SubApp
                app.repository.updateSubscriptionsFromNetwork(result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It got it to resolve by changing
`override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?)` 
to 
`override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage)`

just replace "remoteMessage" with p0 every place in your class.

If you're getting same error for onNewToken also then do this 
change `override fun onNewToken(token: String?)` to `override fun onNewToken(p0: String)`

Comment: The issue is not in how we name the variable (p0 or remoteMessage), it's in declaring the variable as nullable